# Independent clause and main verb

Tags: verbs, clauses

What is the independent clause and main verb in this sentence?

Wall Street's glass ceiling cracked at last on March 1st,as Jane Fraser took charge of Citigroup, becoming the first woman to head a big American bank.

Answer (score 1):

Wall Street's glass ceiling cracked at last on March 1st, *- Main clause*

as Jane Fraser took charge of Citigroup, *- Subordinate clause* modifying "cracked"

becoming the first woman to head a big American bank. *- Participle phrase.* Free modifier of "as Jane Fraser took charge of Citigroup"

Comment: "as Jane Fraser took charge of Citigroup" is a adverbial clause?

Comment: "becoming the first woman to head a big American bank" is a adjective phrase?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. It is adverbial - most free modifiers are adverbial.